# Display server side escaped data with ngModel

Tags: angularjs, xss, angular-ngmodel

I have a webapp in which, for security reasons, the user data is escaped server side before sending it to angular.

So angular receives "& amp;" instead of "&" for example.

I display the data in the webpage as "&" using ng-bind-html. This works fine.

But if I want to edit the value in a text input, I will use ng-model and then the input text is displaying "& amp;"

What is the proper way of displaying "&" in the input text ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try ng-bind-html ?

Comment: Yes. It does nothing on a text input

Comment: [Angular santize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize]) is for you. You can create a filter to edit html.

Comment: I don't see how it fixes the problem. And ng-model won't accept a filter